# How to retrieve empty OPTION value if it's empty?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, select, html-select

Considering we have this HTML:

```
<select id="my_select">
  <option value="1">Foo</option>
  <option value="2">Bar</option>
  <option value="">Bork</option>
  <option value="3">Hey!</option>
</select>
```

The proper way to get the chosen `value` would be:

```
var oS = document.getElementById("my_select");
alert(oS.options[oS.selectedIndex].value);
```

But if the third option, Bork, is chosen, the `alert()` will show `"Bork"` and not `""` (empty string).

How do I retrieve the empty string?

Comment: Can you not give Bork a value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, it doesn't.  For me, in Chrome and IE8, your example alerts an empty string ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3var/)).

If, however, there is no `value` set at all ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3var/1/)), `Bork` is alerted.  This is, I think, the issue you're coming up against.  This is correct behaviour.  As [the MDC page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/option) says,

> If it is not defined, its default value is the text content of the element.

You could, however, use the `getAttribute` method, which gives `null` if no elements are selected ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f3var/2/)).

```
var oS = document.getElementById("my_select");
alert(oS.options[oS.selectedIndex].getAttribute('value'));
```

Comment: @mcgrailm: I think you misread. What your answer described is what is currently happening to the OP, not what they want.

Comment: @mcgrailm: No worries. Happens to me too sometimes. :)

Answer (score 0):

alert(document.getElementById("my_select").value)

returns the empty string, or any defined value of the selected option.

no need to specify options[selectedIndex]

If there is no default selected index, the first option value is returned.

If there is no value attribute for the selected option,

the option's **text** is returned in a script alert in most browsers,

and is sent to the server (if the select has a name and a form action) in all browsers.